# setTimeout and appending objects to the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page with some rows that contain basic information. A user can click on a row to display more information, which requires an ajax call. Depending on the amount of information I'm returning, this ajax call can take a second or two. To let the user know that I'm loading information during this time, I'd like to append some text saying 'Loading'. So before I make my ajax call I append a span with the text 'Loading' and remove it on success. However, even though the ajax can take a second or two, everything must happen fast enough that 'Loading' doesn't appear. If I stop at a breakpoint I can see the loading text. So I decided to use setTimeout with a 0ms wait time, just long enough for the browser to render my 'Loading'.

Here's some example code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var item;
  $('.my-row').click(function() {
    item = $(this).val();
    $(this).children().append('<span id="loading">Loading..</span>');
    setTimeout(function()
    {
      getMyInformation(item, $(this).next().children());
    }, 0);
  });
});

function getMyInformation(item, appendTo) {
  $.ajax({
    url: myUrl,
    async: false,
    type: "POST",
    data: { Id: item.id, Name: item.name },
    success: function (json) {
      $('#loading').remove();
      appendItems(json.items, appendTo);
    }
  });
}

function appendItems(items) {
  $(items).each(function(i, item) {
    appendTo.append('<div>item.info</div>');
  });
}
```

Here's my issue:
Without the setTimeout, the page can seem a little laggy because my 'Loading' doesn't have a chance to appear, but my information does display after the ajax call. With the setTimeout, my 'Loading' appears, and everything else happens as expected, except none of my 'items' are appended. I can set a breakpoint down and watch it run through `appendTo.append('<div>item.info</div>');` for every item I pass it, but they never show in the browser or the DOM. Does anyone know what is going on?

Comment: Using `async:false` is almost always a bad thing - it impacts on the user's experience.  It may even be related to the issue you're seeing, in that it blocks the UI.  It's considered so bad, that [the spec](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#sync-warning) already allows for browsers to experiment with throwing errors when it is used.

Comment: @JamesThorpe I tried the answer I marked as correct and it worked. Then I changed to `async:false` and was able to remove my setTimeout completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `this` inside of your `setTimeout` is no longer the same context - set the variable before hand:

```
var elements = $(this).next().children();
setTimeout(function()
{
  getMyInformation(item, elements);
}, 0);
```

Comment: Of course, that assumes no children are added or removed between when you start the timeout and when it fires.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Well, I dont think anything should be - it's a `0` ms timeout with a UI blocking AJAX call

Comment: This was exactly my issue. I don't know why I didn't think of this in the first place.